# How do I change the formatting of pasted JSON code

Tags: json, format, notepad++

Been googling, but no answer.

I have some JSON dumped out in my log. I copied it and pasted it into a window in Notepad++, but it doesn't seem to be detecting the fact that it's JSON.

How do I tell it that this is JSON and use the special features as such without saving and loading the file?

Comment: Menu Language >> JSON . Doesn't it work?

Comment: @Toto That did it. Looked at all of the menus besides that one. Thought language was English, Spanish, Italian.

Comment: @Toto Please post as answer so I can credit you.

Comment: I've just done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under *Menu* >> *Language* choose *JSON*